# How to find pattern starts and ends with in a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to write a Regex to find lines starting with TCP 0.0.0.0 , ending with ongoing text from a log file.

Log file sample:

```
ensePo#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 100.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy100" ongoing 127410 120891 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0023-00005CD33064
    Line 1896: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 101.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy101" ongoing 127259 120740 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0024-00005CD33064
    Line 1897: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy102" ongoing 130656 124136 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0025-00005CD33064
    Line 1898: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy103" ongoing 130504 123984 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0026-00005CD33064
    Line 1899: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy104" ongoing 130351 123831 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0027-00005CD33064
    Line 1900: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy105" ongoing 130350 123830 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0028-00005CD33064
    Line 1901: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy106" ongoing 130196 123678 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CD33064
    Line 1902: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy107" ongoing 130044 123524 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CD33064
    Line 1903: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy108" ongoing 129890 123371 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002B-00005CD33064
    Line 1904: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy109" ongoing 129739 123220 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002C-00005CD33064
    Line 1905: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 11.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy11" ongoing 137160 130641 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002D-00
```

I want print those lines and count them . New to python please help

Comment: `*string*.split('TCP 0.0.0.0')`?

Comment: Do you mean you want all text after TCP 0.0.0.0 until the next one?

Comment: I want to print and count line containing TCP 0.0.0.0 and ongoing in it

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide sample of what you want to match in the log file. There is no line starting with "TCP 0.0.0.0" in the sample log. And what does  "ending with ongoing text" mean?

Comment: If you see in logs line no 1896 contains TCP 0.0.0.0 and ongoing text in it. So I want to print all those lines containing these 2 words and print count of these lines

Comment: The first line also contains TCP 0.0.0.0 and ongoing...so question still unclear. Regex may be overkill if you just want to test for contains you can use string methods like `line.contains(‘ongoing’)`

Comment: I have not included others logs which doesn't have that pattern.

Comment: Please give example on how the result will look like.

Comment: Output: Line 1901: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy106" ongoing 130196 123678 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CD33064
    Line 1902: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy107" ongoing 130044 123524 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CD33064
    
                                                COUNT:2

Comment: It should just print whole line containing those pattern and print count of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import re

f = open("sample_log.txt", "r")
counter = 0
print("="*20)
for line in f:
    match = re.search("(TCP 0\.0\.0\.0) (.*) (ongoing)", line)
    if match:
        counter += 1
        print("-"*10)

        # If you want to print the whole line
        print("Count {}:[F] {}".format(counter, line.rstrip()))

        # if you want to print just the matched section
        # print("Count {}:[M] {}".format(counter, match.groups()[1].rstrip()))

print("="*20)
print("Total Found: {}".format(counter))
f.close()
```

The output will look like:

```
----------
Count 1:[F] ensePo#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 100.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy100" ongoing 127410 120891 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0023-00005CD33064
----------
Count 2:[F]     Line 1896: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 101.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy101" ongoing 127259 120740 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0024-00005CD33064
----------
Count 3:[F]     Line 1897: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy102" ongoing 130656 124136 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0025-00005CD33064
----------
Count 4:[F]     Line 1898: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy103" ongoing 130504 123984 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0026-00005CD33064
----------
Count 5:[F]     Line 1899: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy104" ongoing 130351 123831 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0027-00005CD33064
----------
Count 6:[F]     Line 1900: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy105" ongoing 130350 123830 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0028-00005CD33064
----------
Count 7:[F]     Line 1901: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy106" ongoing 130196 123678 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CD33064
----------
Count 8:[F]     Line 1902: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy107" ongoing 130044 123524 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CD33064
----------
Count 9:[F]     Line 1903: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy108" ongoing 129890 123371 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002B-00005CD33064
----------
Count 10:[F]     Line 1904: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy109" ongoing 129739 123220 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002C-00005CD33064
----------
Count 11:[F]     Line 1905: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 11.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy11" ongoing 137160 130641 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002D-00
====================
Total Found: 11
```

Given the sample_log.txt being:

```
asdadsfgdsgsd-- SOME JUNK -- fgdfsgdfsg asdfaskdjlfh alkjsdflkahjs jsdfs
ensePo#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 100.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy100" ongoing 127410 120891 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0023-00005CD33064
    Line 1896: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 101.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy101" ongoing 127259 120740 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0024-00005CD33064
asdadsfgdsgsdfgdfsgdfsg asdfaskdjlfh alkjsdflkahjs jsdfs
    Line 1897: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy102" ongoing 130656 124136 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0025-00005CD33064
    Line 1898: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy103" ongoing 130504 123984 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0026-00005CD33064
    Line 1899: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy104" ongoing 130351 123831 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0027-00005CD33064
    Line 1900: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy105" ongoing 130350 123830 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0028-00005CD33064
    Line 1901: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy106" ongoing 130196 123678 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CD33064
    Line 1902: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy107" ongoing 130044 123524 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CD33064
    Line 1903: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy108" ongoing 129890 123371 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002B-00005CD33064
    Line 1904: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy109" ongoing 129739 123220 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002C-00005CD33064
    Line 1905: DefensePro#08-05-2019 15:47:55 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 11.1.1.1 0 15 Regular "policy11" ongoing 137160 130641 N/A 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002D-00
```